# Looking for Unity Projector component for HDRP similar to the one in the built-in render pipeline

Tags: unity-game-engine, projector

Hello Unity HDRP Experts
I'm looking for a projector component for HDRP similar to the one in the built-in render pipeline. The decal projector component doesn't seem suitable for my multi-projector simulator.
It would have to be something like an inverted camera.

Thanks to all